# MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START not found in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am currently working with `Mediaplayer` in `Xamarin` android. There are `MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START` and `MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END` in native android(java). But I cannot find these `MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START` and `MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START` for Xamarin. My code in android studio:

```
  mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            switch (what) {
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                    AppLog.showLogE(TAG,"Buffering...");
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
                    AppLog.showLogE(TAG,"Buffering End");
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In Xamarin Android I am stuck here:

```
    public bool OnInfo(MediaPlayer mp, [GeneratedEnum] MediaInfo what, int extra)
    {
        switch (what)
        {
            case MediaPlayer. //not found

                    break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how you do it on xamarin android,
I hope this is what you are looking for  :

```
 switch (what) {
            case Android.Media.MediaInfo.BufferingStart:
                //AppLog.showLogE(TAG,"Buffering...");
                progressView.Visibility=(ViewStates.Visible);
                break;
            case Android.Media.MediaInfo.BufferingEnd:
                //AppLog.showLogE(TAG,"Buffering End");
                progressView.Visibility=(ViewStates.Gone);
                break;
        }
```

Goodluck!
Happy coding.